# Could not autowire. No beans of 'DataSource' type found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Здравствуйте. Настраиваю Spring Security с использованием базы данных. Выдает следующую ошибку в следующей строке:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'DataSource' type found
>
> @Autowired
>       private DataSource dataSource;

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка или хотя бы в какую сторону смотреть :) 
SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.onlineshop"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

   @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll();
                //.loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login-error"); **/
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Apllication.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlineshop
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить в dependencies spring-boot-starter-data-jpa